# How to place admob smartbanner at fixed position

Tags: layout, admob, height, banner, smartbanner

Normally smart banner ads may take some time to load. During loading the content may took the place of banner ad, later once banner appears the space for content will reduce and adjusted. But it will create a bubbing or jumping effect. It may attract viewers and lead to invalid click. Actually I got a admob disabling due to this. Now I would like to know how to reserve the ad area. **I don't need any other content to take the location of ad while ad loading.** **What I need is, I need to keep smart banner area blank/free while it loading.** (How to keep fixed height for this area) How to do this.

For reference here is the code for smart banner

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Please give a solution